# Getting the global coordinates of a vertex from mouse location

Tags: python, operator, coordinates, mouse

I have a some code here that I combined from other people to test out implementations on how to get the correct global coordinates of the vertex that your mouse is hoovering over.

There are 2 different functions that I try in this code to get the coordinates. One is `bpy.ops.view3d.select()` and the other `view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d()`. The first one tries to select the vertex and returns the index of it so you can look up the coordinates of it and the second function tries to get the location based on your mouse X,Y coordinates and your view.

The `bpy.ops.view3d.select()` is working fine and returns the correct vertex but the `region_2d_to_location_3d()` doesn't really return the X,Y coordinates that are close to the vertex. Is there some kind of additional operation that you need to do for it to get the correct X,Y coordinates?

I've applied transformation to the mesh so there shouldn't be any local vs global issue.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.object is not None and
                context.object.type == 'MESH' and
                context.object.data.is_editmode)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        me = context.object.data
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
        verts_sel = [v.select for v in bm.verts]
        edges_sel = [e.select for e in bm.edges]
        faces_sel = [f.select for f in bm.faces]
        
        loc = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y   
        
        #----region_2d_to_location_3d----
        sob = bpy.context.object           
        region = bpy.context.region
        region3D = bpy.context.space_data.region_3d
        mouse_pos = [event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y]
        #The direction indicated by the mouse position from the current view
        view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, region3D, mouse_pos)            
        #The 3D location in this direction
        ploc = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d(region, region3D, mouse_pos, view_vector)
        #The 3D location converted in object local coordinates           
        ploc = sob.matrix_world.inverted() @ ploc
        print(ploc)
        #-------------------------------
                    
        try:
            geom = bm.select_history[-1]
        except IndexError:
            geom = None
            
        ret = bpy.ops.view3d.select(extend=True, location=loc)
        if ret == {'PASS_THROUGH'}:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "no close-by geom")
            return {'CANCELLED'}            
        
        try:
            geom2 = bm.select_history[-1]
            print("geom2 sel 1st", geom2.select)
        except IndexError:
            geom2 = None

        if geom is None:
            geom = geom2
        
        if isinstance(geom, bmesh.types.BMVert):
            geom_sel = verts_sel
            bm_geom = bm.verts
        elif isinstance(geom, bmesh.types.BMEdge):
            geom_sel = edges_sel
            bm_geom = bm.edges
        elif isinstance(geom, bmesh.types.BMFace):
            geom_sel = faces_sel
            bm_geom = bm.faces

        for sel, g in zip(geom_sel, bm_geom):
            if sel != g.select:
                g.select_set(False)
                bm.select_history.remove(g)
                bm.select_flush_mode()
                break
        
        
        self.report({'INFO'}, repr(geom))
        return {'FINISHED'}


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

register()
```